# I want to create some program with react js, about adding strings in window, but I am having an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a program with React Js, where I need to write something in prompts and it needs to appear in window. Now I have created the function of adding prompts and pasting it in window, but it's giving an error.
please help me if you can : )

```
export default class Clock extends React.Component {
   state = {items: ['Hakob', 'Arman']};

   Add(){
      const newitems = this.state.items.concat([prompt('a')])
      this.setState({items:newitems})
   }

 

   render(){
         return <div>
             <Clock2/> 
         </div>
   }
} 

class Clock2 extends React.Component {


   render(){
      return(
         <>
             <button onClick={this.Add}>click</button>
             
     


         <div> {this.state.items.map((e, i) => {
            return <div key = {e + i}> {e} </div>
         } )} </div>

         </>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: code missing :p

Comment: Please copy & paste the code to your post, as well as the error message

Comment: I had past a link

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzlfD.png

Comment: did you seen it?

Comment: Edit your question to include the text of your code.  Please do not use images of code: if we want to run your code to help figure out what the problem is then we can't copy and paste the code from an image.

Comment: idk y, but at some point, `this.state` is null at least sometimes

Comment: @HaykKirakosyan Don't post a link. Copy the code and error to the question

Comment: I had edited my question and pasted a code... look at that

Answer (score 0):

you have not defined any state in class clock2 so, the line # 798 giving you an error for cannot read property of items as it is not defined in class

```
class Clock2 extends React.Components {
state = {
items : // 
}

}
```

and the second error is you are trying to return in the return function that is not correct if you want to map items you have to define map function in render

```
{
const items = this.state.items.map((e,i ) => {
// 
}
return (
<items/>
)
```

Comment: bro can u give your telegram, I will write you with there and we will fix my bug

Comment: what about instagram ?

Comment: [link] (https://github.com/Hamzaaasif/Reimbursment-Requests/blob/master/Reimbursement-Request/src/containers/UserHome/UserHome.js)

check out this code you can find the map function in which i added the button for every row in a table

Comment: **itz_hamzaa** this is my instagram id

Comment: mine is 1___kirakosyan___0 I will write you now

Answer (score -1):

So let's write your code here.

```
export default class Clock extends React.Component {
   state = { items: ['Hakob', 'Aram']};

   Add() {
      const newItems = this.state.items.concat([prompt('a')])
      this.setState({items:newItems})
   }

   render() {
      return <div><Clock2/><div>
   }
}

class Clock2 extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <>
            <button onClick={this.Add}>Click</button>
            <div>{ this.state.items.map( (e,i) => {
               return <div key={ e + i}>{e}</div>
            })}
            </div>
         </>
      )
   }
}
```

You made a mistake, state are internals to component, as well as method.

This should work

```
export default class Clock extends React.Component {
   state = { items: ['Hakob', 'Aram']};

   Add() {
      const newItems = this.state.items.concat([prompt('a')])
      this.setState({items:newItems})
   }

   render() {
      return (
          <>
            <button onClick={this.Add}>Click</button>
            <div>{ this.state.items.map( (e,i) => {
               return <div key={ e + i}>{e}</div>
            })}
            </div>
         </>
      )
   }
}
```

Or you can pass values from top component to his child.

```
export default class Clock extends React.Component {
   state = { items: ['Hakob', 'Aram']};

   Add() {
      const newItems = this.state.items.concat([prompt('a')])
      this.setState({items:newItems})
   }

   render() {
      return (<div><Clock2 add={this.Add} values={this.state.items}/><div>)
   }
}

class Clock2 extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <>
            <button onClick={this.prop.add}>Click</button>
            <div>{ this.props.values.map( (e,i) => {
               return <div key={ e + i}>{e}</div>
            })}
            </div>
         </>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: it means we dont need Clock2 component yeah?

Comment: Well you can choose two use a single component or pass data/fct correctly to the second one. If you want to learn more, follow some tutorials, they are a great way to learn before making things by yourself.

Comment: Please accept the post edit, I added the code. Then I'll remove it from mine

Comment: Sorry But I can't understand you

Comment: Do you have telegram, I will write you from there and we will fix my bug : /

Comment: You don't have bugs, you're just new to React.. keep learning. Follow tutorials, watch youtube videos, keep going !!! :)